# AFNetworking - Unsupported URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to check if my POST request is working properly using AFNetworking in Objective c. Request is working fine in Android and Postman. Here is my URL: 
`#define API_BASE @"54.191.xx.xxx/XXXXXXXX/index.php/checkout"`

Here are my params:

```
NSDictionary *paramters = @{@"quantity":@"21", @"price":@"10"};
```

This is my code to make the request:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
[manager POST:API_BASE parameters:paramters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}];
```

This code never enters the success block and I am getting an error saying 'Unsupported URL'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of API base ?

Comment: you need to add `http://` to your url.

Comment: I have added http but I am now getting internal server error(500)

Comment: debug your headers and request type with the postman one and make sure they are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `API_BASE` value to include `http://`:

```
#define API_BASE @"http://54.191.26.206/EntropikSDKBackend/index.php/checkout
```

Comment: I have added http but I am now getting internal server error(500)

Comment: That means your PHP-backend throws an error. You can view the logs on the server and go from there. Maybe you're using wrong request-headers.

Answer (score 1):

`54.191.xx.xxx/XXXXXXXX/index.php/checkout` is not a valid URL.  You need to specify the scheme.  Likely `http://` or `https://`.

Note: `http` and `https` are the schemes.  `://` is just part of the URL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add `http://` to your `API_BASE`, like so:

```
#define API_BASE @"http://54.191.26.206/EntropikSDKBackend/index.php/checkout
```

You will most likely also need to add an ATS exception to your info.plist to allow unencryped traffic to the host 54.191.26.206

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the network reference path. Any URL you are providing should also need the network reference path for communication and to decide which scheme/protocol need to be used.